# Trying to get property 'img' of non-object using Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I am creating a Laravel e-commerce site and I am using the Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ library. I am having an issue with the 'Add To Cart' button. I'll explain a bit more! I have a singleProduct.blade.php file and this calls the product info from a controller:

This is the function that passes the data from the DB to the view:

```php
public function show($name)
{
    $iamlush = iamlush::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();

    return view('singleProduct')->with('product', $iamlush);
}
```

This is the singleProduct file:

```html
<div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="rowContainer text-center">
        <div class="productImgContainer">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/iamlush/shop/'.$product->img) }}" class="productImg">
        </div>

        <div class="productInfoContainer">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="productLogoContainer">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/logo/'.$product->productLogo) }}" class="logoContainer">
                </div>

                <h3>{{ $product->name }}</h3>
                <h5>{{ $product->priceFormat() }}</h5>
             </div>

             <p class="descriptionContainer">
                 {{ $product->description }}
             </p>

             <div class="rowContainer">
                 <div class="iconContainer">
                     <img src="{{ asset('img/productPage/productInfo.png') }}" class="icons">
                 </div>

             <div class="iconContainer">
                 <img src="{{ asset('img/productPage/paymentMethods.jpg') }}" class="icons">
             </div>
         </div>

         <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST" class="formContainer">
             @csrf
             <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
             <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $product->name }}">
             <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ $product->price }}">

             <div class="BtnContainer">
                 <button type="submit" class="btnCart">Add To Cart</button>
             </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 'Add To Cart' sends a POST request to the 'cart.store' and this is the web.php:

```php
Route::post('/cart', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
```

This is the cart controller file:

```php
public function store(Request  $request)
{
    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)->associate('App\iamlush');

    return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');
}
```

The cart page as several Laravel sections. The first is the passing of the success message if the item is succesfully added:

```php
@if (session()->has('success_message'))
    <p class="itemAddedContainer">
        {{ session()->get('success_message') }}
    </p>
@endif
```

The second is the the actual cart function, it checks wether the count for the cart is above 0 i.e. there is items in the cart:

```html
@if(\Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::count() > 0)
                <p class="introTxt">Looks like you have {{ \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::count() }} Let's see what you have in your bag...</p>

                <div class="rowContainer">
                    <!-- holds labels for cart -->
                    <div class="labelContainer">
                        <p>Product Image</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="labelContainer">
                        <p>Name</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="labelContainer">
                        <p>Quantity</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="labelContainer">
                        <p>Price</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

After this section, before the @else and @endif for 'count() > 0', is the @foreach loop in the cart:

```html
@foreach( \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::content() as $item)
                    <div class="productRowContainer">
                        <!-- holds labels for cart -->
                        <div class="cartItemContainer">
                            <img src="{{ asset('img/iamlush/shop/'.$item->model->img) }}" style="width: 30%;">
                        </div>

                        <div class="cartItemContainer">
                            <div class="dataContainer">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img/logo/'.$item->model->productLogo) }}" class="productLogo">
                                <p>Mediterranean Dark</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="cartItemContainer">
                            <div class="dataContainer">
                                <div class="quantityContainer">
                                    <button class="quantityBtn">-</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="quantityContainer">
                                    <p>1</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="quantityContainer">
                                    <button class="quantityBtn">+</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="cartItemContainer">
                            <div class="dataContainer">
                                <p>{{ $item->model->presentprice() }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <h3>You dont have anything</h3>
            @endif
```

This section takes the content of the cart as $item and is then used to fill the data. I am following this youtube tutorial:

Laravel E-Commerce - Shopping Cart - Part 2 ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzi6aLKVw-A&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5oPTli631ZX9cxl6cU_sDaR&index=4&t=430s )

At 13.00 minutes is when he makes it dynamic and when I first tried it, it worked for me but then it stopped working out of the blue and I can't understand why and it was giving me this error:

```
Trying to get property 'img' of non-object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to debug your query result

```
dd($iamlush)
```

if there is null, check your database? have you any records by that name
there may be two reason

1. you doesn't have any record for this condition
2. you have a mistake in your model

Comment: I know the $iamlsuh variable work bc all the data is successfully pulled for the single product page the issue is the adding it to the cart form the singleProduct.blade.php

Comment: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#user-content-models
i recommend you to view this part of documentation
$cartItem->associate('Product');
method doesn't include App -model path